# VB.NET How to rename image in MemoryStream?

Tags: vb.net, file, renaming

Well the title pretty much says it all. If I have an image in a file stream like so:

```
Dim imgStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
sd.Save(imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

How would I rename this file to a GUID I have made. Right now this is the method I am trying however "sd" is highlighted and says "Value of type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' cannot be converted to 'String'"

Here is the code for making the GUID:

```
Dim newName As String
newName = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString()
```

and here is the code for renaming...

```
Rename(sd, newName)
```

I'm sure it's something stupid but any help would be much appreciated! Also, I'm a complete noob! So don't hate if it's completely wrong lol. Thanks in advance!

Also, if this is needed here is the code for how the image is being generated(it's taking     image of desktop):

```
sd = New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width, _
My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height, _
Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(sd)
g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), _
New Size(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width, _
My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height))
```

Comment: Thank you for editing it. Beat me to it!

Comment: In memory "files" don't have names, so there is nothing to rename. What you are trying to do isn't clear to me, are you trying to rename a file already written to disk?

Comment: @vcsjones Ah I see now... well I'm taking an image of the desktop and later uploading it to an FTP account. But I need to rename the screenshot before it's uploaded. Possible?

Comment: You can save the file how you want, just upload the file to the FTP and rename

Answer (score 3):

It's not a file. There is no file. There is only a collection of bytes with a certain pleasing arrangement that exist only in memory and will cease to exist the moment your program terminates. Until you write that MemoryStream to disk somewhere, there is no such thing as a file, and therefore no name for you to change.

When you take the MemoryStream and write it to a file on disk, you can then give it whatever name you want at the point you create an empty file and open it for writing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sd As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(sd)
g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), New Size(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height))
Dim newName As String
newName = "C:\Junk\" & System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString() & ".JPG"
sd.Save(newName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
MsgBox("Done")
```

Comment: when using this code I got an error pointing at the "Jpeg" on the second to last line saying "A generic error occurred in DGI+" any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a filesystem error - maybe the folder C:\Junk doesn't exist, or you don't have write permission etc.

Comment: is there anyway to achieve this by not putting it on a folder on the local PC?

Comment: Where would you want it? On your ftp server? Can't you just delete the file after you've uploaded it?